# How to avoid repetition in a "location" section?

Tags: nginx

I have a web app bening nginx. A part of my nginx config:

```
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:4000 https://domain123.net;
  }
```

To add basic authentication to "/admin", I have to do this:

```
  location /admin {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/admin;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:4000/admin https://domain123.net/admin;

    auth_basic "who?";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }
```

How can I avoid repetition **proxy_NNN** for "/admin"?

Comment: Put the repeated stuff in an `include`.

Comment: @ceejayoz, post your answer

Answer (score 2):

Put the repeated stuff in an `include`.

Comment: show me an example

Comment: Plenty of examples in the nginx docs for `include`.